# Using linq group by statement as a subquery

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query which works fine:

```
var bands = new List<TimeBand>()
            {
                new TimeBand(){Region = 10,PeriodId = 5,StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 04, 01),EndDate = new DateTime(2014, 05, 31),DayName = "Friday",StartTime = "00:00",EndTime = "07:00"},
                new TimeBand(){Region = 10,PeriodId = 5,StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 04, 01),EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 05, 31),DayName = "Friday",StartTime = "07:00",EndTime = "00:00"},
                new TimeBand(){Region = 10,PeriodId = 4,StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 06, 01),EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 08, 31),DayName = "Saturday",StartTime = "20:00",EndTime = "00:00"}
            };

    var query = (from x in bands
                group x by new {x.Region, x.DayName}
                into grp
                    select new TimeBand()
                    {
                        Region = grp.Key.Region,
                        DayName = grp.Key.DayName,
                        StartDate = grp.Min(x => x.StartDate),
                        EndDate = grp.Max(x => x.EndDate)
                    }).ToList();
```

But as I group the results by Region and Dayname I am not getting the other columns in my result i.e StartTime and EndTime.

If this was a SQL query I would have used this grouped results in a subquery and get the other columns as well.

Is there any way of modifying this so I also get the properties which are not included in the group by statement.

Thanks

Comment: `grp` implements `IEnumerable<>`, which has all the columns. You are simply not selecting them right now.

Comment: @03Usr That's because there isn't just one value.  Each item in the sequence represents a sequence of items.  You can iterate *that* to get each sub item.  You can then pull out the column values from any of those items.

Comment: Thanks Servy / Tim S I have debugged and seen it.

Comment: What's your desired output? I run your example and got what I would expect:
    (10 Friday 01.04.2013 31.05.2014),(10 Saturday 01.06.2013 31.08.2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping source items you have sequence of groups. How you will project these groups is up to you. Usually you select grouping keys and some aggregated values on each group (that is how SQL works). But you can select each group itself, or first item from each group, or some value from last group item:

```
from b in bands
group b by new { b.Region, b.DayName } into g
select new {
   g.Key.Region,
   g.Key.DayName,
   StartDate = g.Min(x => x.StartDate),
   EndDate = g.Max(x => x.EndDate),
   AllBandsFromGroup = g,
   FirstBand = g.First(),
   LastBandPeriod = g.Last().Period
}
```

Comment: To your last comment, no it doesn't.  `x` has left scope after the `group by`.

Comment: @Servy hold on, I'll check

Comment: @Servy yep you are right - didn't know that grouping 'closes' visibility of query variable. Thanks

Comment: Same thing happens with a group join

Answer (score 1):

Just select out the whole group if you want the keys as well as all of the values for all of the items in the groups:

```
select grp;
```

The other option is to select out a sequence of all values of the columns that you want from a group:

```
select new TimeBand()
{
    Region = grp.Key.Region,
    DayName = grp.Key.DayName,
    StartDates = grp.Select(x => x.StartDate),
    EndDates = grp.Select(x => x.EndDate)
}
```

You'd only need to do this if you didn't want to pull down the data for some number of other columns.  If you want all of the columns, just use the first option.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from x in bands
                     group x by new { x.Region, x.DayName }
                         into grp
                         select new 
                         {
                             Region = grp.Key.Region,
                             DayName = grp.Key.DayName,
                             MinStartDate = grp.Min(x => x.StartDate),
                             AllStartDates = grp.Select(k => k.StartDate).ToList(),
                             EndDate = grp.Max(x => x.EndDate),
                             AllEndDates = grp.Select(k => k.EndDate).ToList(),
                         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are trying to find the minimum start date **and** time and maximum end date **and** time for each group. This might be much easier if you combine date and time into a single property.

Otherwise you will need a `IComparer<TimeBand>` for start date and time and another one for end date and time.

If you don't want to combine date and time you can write methods to get the combined values:

```
public DateTime GetStart()
{
    int hour = int.Parse(StartTime.Substring(0, 2));
    int minute = int.Parse(StartTime.Substring(3, 2));

    return new DateTime(StartDate.Year, StartDate.Month, StartDate.Day, hour, minute, 0);
}

public DateTime GetEnd()
{
    int hour = int.Parse(EndTime.Substring(0, 2));
    int minute = int.Parse(EndTime.Substring(3, 2));

    return new DateTime(EndDate.Year, EndDate.Month, EndDate.Day, hour, minute, 0);
}
```

Now you can group the bands and for each group find the minimum start and maximum end:

```
var query = from x in bands
            group x by new
                       {
                           x.Region,
                           x.DayName
                       }
            into grp
            select new TimeBand()
                   {
                       Region = grp.Key.Region,
                       DayName = grp.Key.DayName,
                       StartDate = grp.Min(x => x.StartDate),
                       StartTime = grp.Min(x => x.GetStart()).ToShortTimeString(),
                       EndDate = grp.Max(x => x.EndDate),
                       EndTime = grp.Max(x => x.GetEnd()).ToShortTimeString(),
                   };
```

This is however not very elegant. I would prefer to combine date and time in the first place.